# how can i Refresh code in realtime in vscode

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please help, I want to update changes that i make in my asp.net code in vscode to be reflected in the browser directly on refreshing in the site browser and saving on vscode.
Right now i have to run the dotnet app to see every single change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your dotnet app with `dotnet watch run`.

This way you're telling dotnet to watch for file changes. Now if you change a file and manually reload your browser you should see the change reflected.